# MySQL in node.js, error when attempting to connect

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am having trouble connecting to a database using the MySQL module in node.js. I can't seem to find out exactly why, and the resources seem to be very limited. From my research I have found similar errors in v4.0 and v4.2, but the version of node that I am running is v6.2.2.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,      
  host            : 'psegds-dev',
  port        : '5123',
  user            : 'Admin',
  password        : 'password',
  database        : 'EROUNDS_ADMIN'
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) console.error(err);

    console.log("In getConnection");        
    //connection.release();

});
```

With this code I receive the following error:

```
In getConnection
{ Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:160:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Handshake._onTimeout (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:126:8)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:136:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node.js\server.js:46:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
  code: 'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT',
  fatal: true,
  timeout: 10000 }
error
```

There is a long pause and the print statement is not executed until the error shows up which tells me the getConnection() function is failing. When I include functions like:

```
connection.release();
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields)
```

Then I get typeerrors like this:

```
                 connection.release();
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined
    at C:\node.js\server.js:69:15
    at Handshake.onConnect (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:58:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:85:24)
    at C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:399:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\node.js\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:13
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I have tried using the pool variable instead of the connection variable when running the query() and release() functions. I have tried setting up a single connection, opposed to the pool, but using similar code and got the same errors. I am able to log onto the server with my credentials so I know they're correct.

I have the following c# server code from a working connection string

```
connection string=&quot;data source=psegds-dev,5123;initial 
catalog=*password*;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

C# is not my strongest language, but I don't see what is applicable as well as different from my code. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this in node.js with MySQL, however your problem likely stems from this attribute in your C# connection string: `integrated security=True`. I.e. your password setting is irrelevant, and it expects you to connect with SSPI. Curious how to do this with node.js's mysql...